# Organic groups content propagation direction

Tags: organic-groups

where can I set content propagation direction in Organic groups (7.x-2.x). Post https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40835/need-groups-within-a-group/175000 shows screen which I can not find even though I have installed modules Organic groups and Subgroups for organic groups.

[image]

Do you have any advice where can I find this screen or any other way I could set proparation of content from parent to children groups?

Answer (score 2):

That screenshot is from Drupal 6.

In Drupal 7 the organic groups module works much differently in that it now uses fields to store its settings.

With Drupal 7 organic groups you need to go the the "OG field settings" administration page (admin/config/group/fields) and configure which fields appear on which content types.

The way that admin page works can be a little confusing but it's fairly straight forward once you get used to it.

The fields provided by the [Subgroups for Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_subgroups) module are:

- Group user inheritance
- Group user permission inheritance

On that admin page add those fields to your sub-group content types, then you can go to the content type field settings for those content types (in the admin/structure/types section) and you can configure default for those fields that will be used whenever sub-groups are created.

If you want to stop content administrators from being able to change the value of that field you can then use the [field permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module to restrict access to those 2 fields.

This is the same way you have to manage the fields from the base OG module (Group and Groups audience) and the fields in the OG access sub-module (Group visibility and Group content visibility).

Answer (score 0):

rooby, I tried to set up user membership inheritance using fields Group user inheritance and Group user permission inheritance, but user membership is not inherited.

I've read other posts describing how to set up subgroups with user inheritance, but it doesn't work for me.

I want to create different products P1, P2,... and assign content to them. Then create several groups G1, G2,... for user management. I would like to subscribe group G to product P (as a subgroup), so that users in group G would be able to see content from group P.

I tried two solutions: (A) Set up content inheritance from parent group P to subgroup G, but I couldn't make it work with Subgroups for D7 (subgroups 7.x-2.x has only user inheritance) (B) use reverse approach:

group P has parents G1, G2
on G1 and G2 have set user inheritance to children groups (so when I add user U to group G1, it will also become member of P- this user will see content from groups P and G1, but not the content from G2)
This is current situation: I have 2 groups (Content types): Product and Group.

Product: has fields

"Group audience" (to set parent group Group),
"Group visibility" (Private - accessible only to group members),
Group roles and permission (Use default roles and permissions)
Group content visibility (tried public and private)
Group: has fields

Group visibility (Private - accessible only to group members)
Groups views (none set)
Group roles and permissions (Private (only author and administrators can edit and view))
Group user inheritance (Yes - subgroups of this group will inherit its users.)
Group user permission inheritance (Inherit Permissions - inherited users in this group's subgroups will have the permissions as they do in this group and not the permissions of generic members of that subgroup.)
Group content visibility (Private- accessible only to group members)
Expected behaviour: When I add user to group G1, it should also become member of group P, but it does not.

Am I missing something? Are my settings wrong?